# How do these two functions defined in the same class manage to call each other without forward declaration?

Tags: c++, function, forward-declaration

For the time I'm learning to code with boost/asio. Many code samples make use of the combination of async_accept and bind. In the server code , i come across some thing like this:

```
class Tcp_server
{
public:
    Tcp_server()
    {

    }
    void start_accept(int a)
    {
        if(a>0)
        {
            cout<<a<<endl;
            handle_accept(a-1);
        }

    }

    void handle_accept(int a)
    {
        if(a>0)
        {
            cout<<a<<endl;
            start_accept(a-1);
        }

    }
};
```

If i make an instance of Tcp_server and call either handle_accept or start accept, it works. But if I drop the Tcp_server class encapsulation, the compiler would complain  "handle_accept is not declared". I'm just wondering if the compiler automatically forward declare all the functions defined in the same class. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Functions defined in the definition of a class have exactly the same semantics as if they are only declared in the class definition and then defined immediately after the class definition. The only difference is that such member functions are implicitly declared inline while a function definition is either not-inline or explicitly inline. That is, from the compiler's point of view the functions are declared and the class is defined before the function definitions are considered.

The reason for defining the function after the class definition is simple: without doing so, the class would be incomplete and look-ups of members would fail which is clearly not desirable for member function definitions. As a side effect, functions can readily refer to each other. Since defining member functions in the class definition is primarily for convenience it would also be somewhat inconvenient to require declaration for member functions used later.

Comment: But isn't the question is why this design decision was (probably) made? I'm very curious to know, BTW.

Comment: just as @Drop said, what's the rationale behind this?

Comment: @Drop The reason for this decision is that if the standard was to require a forward declaration in cases when declarations are combined with definitions, defining functions inside the class would become significantly less convenient, to the point where one could stop using the feature altogether.

Comment: @Drop: I updated the answer. The short version: without the class definition being complete, member functions wouldn't be able to do much anyway. Declarations not being necessarily is a nice extra benefit.

Comment: So, if I understand correct, as `handle_accept(a-1);` is really `this->handle_accept(a-1);` and `this` should have complete type, we should know all class methods (including inherited and templated) before that point. That's why compiler parses whole class anyway. Is that so?

Comment: @Drop: I hadn't mentioned the `this->` part but that's true as well. The reasoning, indeed, applies to all methods independent on whether they are inherited, templated, or whatever.